# How to check if the user has NSSharingService to post on Facebook?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm making an OSX App just for 10.8+. Since 10.8 there's the NSSharingService, but the Facebook service only appeared on 10.8.2.
How can i check if the user has the Facebook service?

Comment: Did the answer below not work? If so, please let me know what the problem was.

Comment: when u answered it that felt the right way to check, but if i do that the system preferences window is opened, the accounts and stuff window is shown and an OSX message appears saying something like "Facebook plugin <some random code here> not found"

Comment: Ok, that does not seem to happen to me when I query for a non existant service on a newer OS version. Good to know though, thanks, I'll remove the answer not to mislead anyone.